# wxpython call a function when focus of TextCtrl changes

Tags: python, wxpython

Morning, I would like to call a function in my GUI in the event that the content of a TextCtrl is changed. Only after the user leaves the TextCtrl object though, not during editing.

Please can you help me find the right event handler to use, I'm very new to wxpython and I can't even find a list of allowable events.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the `TextCtrl` to `wx.EVT_TEXT` to capture changes to the value and `wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS` to trigger an even when the focus changes. Alternatively you could bind it to `wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS` and save the current `TextCtrl` value and also bind to it `wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS` to and compare the new value to see if it's changed.

**------- EDIT -------**

[WxFormBuilder](https://github.com/wxFormBuilder/wxFormBuilder) is fantastic tool for quickly creating basic UIs. It will also show you every event that you can bind to a widget by clicking on the 'events'` tab.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried WxFormBuilder originally, but couldn't understand how to build the gui up and get the structure I wanted. I've actually had a lot more success programming the gui from scratch. Is that strange?

Comment: No. It's best to learn from scratch. Wxformbuilder is great for automating the somewhat tedious process of organizing sizers and windows in a visual way that's much easier than trying to accomplish (at least for me) mentally. Did this answer solve your question?